# Selecting some results of SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

From a simple SQL query in MySQL how can I get only the 5 first results?
And then, how can I get the next 5 results?

For example (pseudo code):

```
select * from (select * from some_table) where <first 5 results>
select * from (select * from some_table) where <second 5 results (6-10)>
```

Comment: What prevents you from getting the first 10 results in one shot?

Comment: Different results for different occasions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the first 5 results with a `LIMIT 5` at the end of your statement:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 5;
```

And then you can get results 6-10 with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5;
```

As another example, you could get results 6-15 with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5;
```

Please keep in mind that, if you don't add an `ORDER BY` statement, the results are retrieved in arbitrary order. Consequently, it doesn't really make sense to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in the absence of an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I think my example might have been too simple. Would your solution still work if my query looked like this: `SELECT * FROM some_table where some_field > 11 `?

Comment: You can definitely add a WHERE clause and have things still work. The real problem is that, if you don't guarantee an ORDER, it doesn't really make sense to say that you want the "first 5 rows" or "rows 6-10". Let's say you have a table, "name_table" that has one column, "first_name", with values "Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", and "Dave". If you do SELECT * FROM name_table LIMIT 1, you could get any of the values, but if you do SELECT * FROM name_table ORDER BY first_name LIMIT 1, then you will definitely get "Alice"

Comment: I just found out there's no need to use OFFSET. LIMIT can be followed by 2 numbers - the first and last result.So, `LIMIT 0, 5` will give the first 5 results. `LIMIT 5, 5` will give results 6-10, and so on.

Comment: correction - the second number says how many results to count from the first number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making a SQL union

```
select * from (select * from some_table) where <first 5 results>
UNION ALL 
select * from (select * from some_table) where <second 5 results (6-10)>
```